# Rubi/Mathematica gives different values for the same integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, rubi

Consider this integral:
$$
\int_0^\pi d\theta \sin\theta\, {1 \over \gamma^q}\left((1-\gamma^2)^2\sqrt{1 \over 1-\left(1-(1-\gamma^2)^4\right)\cos^2\theta} - 1\right)^q
$$
for $0\leq \gamma < 1$. We can caclulate it directly, or integrate

$$
\int_0^\pi d\theta \sin\theta\, {1 \over \gamma^q}\left(b\sqrt{1 \over 1-a \cos^2\theta} - 1\right)^q
$$
and afterward replace $b\to (1-\gamma^2)^2$ and $a \to \left(1-(1-\gamma^2)^4\right)$. Also, the term $1/\gamma^q$ is a constant and can be inside or outside the integration. So, there are four scenarios. Below is the code for these scenarios that uses Rubi for integration.

Here is the code:

```
<< Rubi`

For[q = 1, q <= 15,

  A1 = Assuming[
    gamma ∈ Reals && 0 <= gamma < 1 && theta >= 0 && theta ∈ Reals,
    Int[Sin[theta] 1/gamma^q ((1 - gamma^2)^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4) Cos[theta]^2)] - 1)^q, theta]];
  A2 = 1/gamma^q Assuming[
     gamma ∈ Reals && 0 <= gamma < 1 && theta >= 0 && theta ∈ Reals,
     Int[Sin[theta] ((1 - gamma^2)^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4) Cos[theta]^2)] - 1)^q, theta]];
  A3 = Assuming[
     gamma ∈ Reals && 0 <= gamma < 1 && a ∈ Reals && 0 <= a < 1 && b ∈ Reals && 0 <= b < 1 && theta >= 0 && theta ∈ Reals,
     Int[Sin[theta] 1/gamma^q (b Sqrt[1/(1 - a Cos[theta]^2)] - 1)^q, theta]] /. {a -> (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4), b -> (1 - gamma^2)^2};
  A4 = 1/gamma^q Assuming[
      gamma ∈ Reals && 0 <= gamma < 1 && a ∈ Reals && 0 <= a < 1 && b ∈ Reals && 0 <= b < 1 && theta >= 0 && theta ∈ Reals,
      Int[Sin[theta] (b Sqrt[1/(1 - a Cos[theta]^2)] - 1)^q, theta]] /. {a -> (1 - (1 - gamma^2)^4), b -> (1 - gamma^2)^2};

  B1 = Limit[A1, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"] - Limit[A1, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
  B2 = Limit[A2, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"] - Limit[A2, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
  B3 = Limit[A3, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"] - Limit[A3, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
  B4 = Limit[A4, theta -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"] - Limit[A4, theta -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];

  Print["---------------------------------------"];
  Print["q = ", q, " --> B1/.gamma\[Rule] 0.1 = ", B1 /. gamma -> 0.1];
  Print["q = ", q, " --> B2/.gamma\[Rule] 0.1 = ", B2 /. gamma -> 0.1];
  Print["q = ", q, " --> B3/.gamma\[Rule] 0.1 = ", B3 /. gamma -> 0.1];
  Print["q = ", q, " --> B4/.gamma\[Rule] 0.1 = ", B4 /. gamma -> 0.1];
  q = q + 1;

  ];
```

As you see below, for small values of $q$ all the four approaches give the same value, but as $q$ increases they start to give different values. I am curious about what is the problem here and how to fix it? which outcome is the correct value?

```
---------------------------------------
q = 1 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.266929
q = 1 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.266929
q = 1 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.266929
q = 1 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.266929
---------------------------------------
q = 2 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0426047
q = 2 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0426047
q = 2 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0426047
q = 2 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0426047
---------------------------------------
q = 3 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.00727758
q = 3 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.00727758
q = 3 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.00727758
q = 3 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.00727758
---------------------------------------
q = 4 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0012885
q = 4 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0012885
q = 4 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0012885
q = 4 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0012885
---------------------------------------
q = 5 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.000233249
q = 5 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.000233249
q = 5 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.000233249
q = 5 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.000233249
---------------------------------------
q = 6 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0000428724
q = 6 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0000428599
q = 6 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0000428777
q = 6 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0000428777
---------------------------------------
q = 7 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -7.95808*10^-6
q = 7 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -7.95808*10^-6
q = 7 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -8.10966*10^-6
q = 7 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -8.2423*10^-6
---------------------------------------
q = 8 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 7.62939*10^-6
q = 8 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 8 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 1.51582*10^-6
q = 8 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 4.26326*10^-6
---------------------------------------
q = 9 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.00012207
q = 9 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.0000568434
q = 9 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.0000247955
q = 9 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.000033091
---------------------------------------
q = 10 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.00195313
q = 10 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 10 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 10 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
---------------------------------------
q = 11 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 11 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.0227374
q = 11 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.0117188
q = 11 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -0.0113687
---------------------------------------
q = 12 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -1.
q = 12 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 12 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 12 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
---------------------------------------
q = 13 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 16.
q = 13 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -9.09495
q = 13 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
q = 13 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = 0.
---------------------------------------
q = 14 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = -256.
q = 14 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = -363.798
q = 14 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = -128.
q = 14 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -181.899
---------------------------------------
q = 15 --> B1/.gamma-> 0.1 = 8192.
q = 15 --> B2/.gamma-> 0.1 = 3637.98
q = 15 --> B3/.gamma-> 0.1 = 2048.
q = 15 --> B4/.gamma-> 0.1 = -1818.99
```

Comment: Rather than building a table showing the different values, it might better to just plot the two results, or plot the difference.  Also, how certain are you that you took into careful consideration the cut structure of the integrand when applying the fundamental theorem of calc?

Comment: I executed your code, then noticed that `Simplify[A1 == A2 == A3 == A4]` returns `True`, so the expressions obtained from integration are all equivalent. So any difference must come from the limits you are taking. As @QuantumDot mentioned, this suggests to me that perhaps calculating the definite integral might require more careful attention than taking the difference of the limits.

Comment: It is possible that the expressions are not well conditioned. I'll suggest using higher precision for the numerical evaluations to see if that brings the results into conformity.